# IE uses img src as href

Tags: image, hyperlink

I have the following code in a textwidget

```
<div class="social">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/peakit.nl" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.peaktest.nl/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon.png" border="0" alt="facebook"></a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/peak-it" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.peaktest.nl/wp-content/uploads/linkedin-icon.png" border="0" alt="linkedin"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/PEAKIT" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.peaktest.nl/wp-content/uploads/twitter-icon.png" border="0" alt="twitter"></a>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/peakit" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.peak-it.nl/wp-content/uploads/youtube-icon.png" border="0" alt="youtube"></a>
</div>
```

This works fine in all browsers except IE8 and IE9.
If I click the image it will load a page with the image (img src url). When I right click the image and open in another tab it will shwo the correct page (href).

What am I missing here?

This is the IE output:

```
<div class="social">

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/peakit.nl" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" alt="facebook" src="http://www.peaktest.nl/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon.png"></a>

    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/peak-it" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" alt="linkedin" src="http://www.peaktest.nl/wp-content/uploads/linkedin-icon.png"></a>

    <a href="https://twitter.com/PEAKIT" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" alt="twitter" src="http://www.peaktest.nl/wp-content/uploads/twitter-icon.png"></a>

    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/peakit" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" alt="youtube" src="http://www.peak-it.nl/wp-content/uploads/youtube-icon.png"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: http:www.peak-it.nl It's the 4 social media icons in the red sidebar

Comment: It looks like there's additional jquery effecting that stuff. I'd start there.

Comment: Thanks for that but how can you tell?
I have no clue as to which script that could be.

Comment: When I look at the source with Developer Tools you can see some attributes added by jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip! It turned out to be the Google Analytics Suite plugin the customer had installed that used a jquery script that interfered. We deactivated it and, all is working fine now